# DES/CBC : incorrect first 8 bytes

Tags: encryption, des

Question about DES-CBC : how to know IV if I have key, input buffer (plaintext),  output buffer (encrypted) and decrypted result where first 8 bytes are incorrect but all other bytes are correct ?"